# Get computer time format in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display date and time according to the users time format on the local computer in my application. 
For example, if local computer displays time in 24hr format, my application should display time in 24hr format. If it is 12hr format, the application should display it in 12 hr format. I want to get the below settings in code and display date and time accordingly.

[image: Local computer clock settings]

Existing code of my application uses DateTime.UtcNow and I should not change it to use DateTime.Now

```
    `public static DateTime FormatTime()
     {
       return DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
     }`
```

It displays time in 12hr format irrespective of time format of the computer. Is there a way to get users computer time format?

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a coding service, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Edit the question with the specific problem you are facing

Comment: What you seem to ask for is not "computer time format" but the current users time format on the local computer.

Comment: You should find the answers you need here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

BTW, is usually much more well received here when you search a bit on the subject and try something before posting a question. We are not here to give the code you need just like that, we are here to help you fix your code if it doesn't work. Next time, search a bit on google, try something from what you find, and then if it doesn't work come here and post the code you have a done and a good explanation of the problem, and people will be happy to help.

Comment: I have updated my question. Waiting for your replies...

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do that. Your application will already do that if you localize it properly.

If you have a `DateTime`, doing something like

```
textBox1.Text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

will already work. The same goes for parsing dates/times. It's best to read the MSDN about localizing and globalizing .NET applications. You'd be amazed how much is done for you already. Don't re-invent the wheel...

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
//formatted using the ShortDatePattern
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d"), CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);
```

CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture is the operating system language

Comment: I would recommend against that. You should rely on the current thread's UI culture. This defaults to the OS culture, but can also be changed, for example if you want to support multiple languages and cultures in your application for the user to choose from.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar You are absolutely right, but the guy is asking about the OS context not the  app context, but this will make more sense to have the Culture set on the app (as default OS culture), or the one set/selected by the user at some point.

Answer (score 0):

When using `DateTime.ToString` always use the Standard Format Strings (e.g. `"d"` for Short Date) instead of Custom Format Strings (e.g. `"yyyy-MM-did"`) and always explicitly specify `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` for the `IFormatProvider` parameter to ensure your intent is clear to whoever reads your code.

Answer (score 0):

The format for the current user can be read by using the `DateTimeFormat` property of a `CultureInfo` object, which is defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat(v=vs.110).aspx), as follows.

```
var iDateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried in my application and here by default it is taking according to system date time format only. When i am changing system time, application time is also changing automatically. I tried in window application with datetime control. What and how you are doing?

Comment: Existing code of my application uses DateTime.UtcNow and I should not change it to use DateTime.Now

    `public static DateTime FormatTime()
     {
       return DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
     }`
It displays time in 12hr format irrespective of time format of the computer.